How to access the div from the child component in JS of parent component (LWC)
I have a div with class 'onScroll reportScrollContainer' in a child component and I want to access this div in JS of the parent component so that I can modify it's CSS at run time. Is it possible to this?
I tried using this.template.querySelector('onScroll reportScrollContainer'); but it returns null.

You cannot access child HTML, because of Shadow DOM.
However, you can create a public method in a child component.
// child.js
@api getDiv() {
   return this.template.querySelector('onScroll reportScrollContainer');
}

And you can invoke it from a parent.
// parent.html
<template>
  <c-my-child lwc:ref="child"></c-my-child>
</template>

// parent.js
parentMethod() {
   const childDiv = this.refs.child.getDiv();
}


It would surely be better to provide a means for the parent to request styling changes in the child? Returning the div to the parent is a bad idea as you have broken encapsulation and the parent could go wild with whatever it wants - adding in huge quantities of markup, or even detaching the div and inserting it somewhere else in the DOM... this is providing a way to break the whole concept of components that encapsulate their details and provide an appropriate API to control their own behaviour.

Yes, of course, agree with you. We don't know the author's idea, and I am not sure it's our job to understand it. Otherwise, we should discuss every StackExchange question before providing the answer.

We should always consider best practice and where it is not followed either provide a clear warning or not provide the answer, IMO.

Make sense, I will apply that to my next answers. Thanks!

You can add a warning here... you can edit your answer.

@PhilW totally agree. the better solution would be parent component calling the child comp method and let child update the styles.
